# Given an iterable of sets, and a name (string), return a set of names which is connected with the given "name"

Tags: python, set

Given a name (as a string) and an iterable of sets, containing two names (as strings), return a new set consisting of names that share a set with the given name.

For example:

```
 itr = ({"a", "b"}, {"b", "c"}, {"c", "a"})
 name = "a"
 newset = {"b", "c"}
```

I'm looking for a pythonic way of approaching this problem. This is the current mess that I have:

```
def friends(itr, name):
    newset = []
    for i in itr:
        if name in i:
            for j in i:
                if j != name:
                    newset.append(j)
    return set(newset)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm relatively new to Python and programming in general. Thank you

Comment: That code seems to work perfectly, what is the problem? http://ideone.com/zbppGA

Comment: Yes the code works, however i was hoping for something a bit more "pythonic"

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> set(e for s in itr for e in s if name in s) - set((name,))
set(['c', 'b'])
```

Comment: `set(y for x in itr for y in x if name in x and y != name)` makes this simpler in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> reduce(set.union, filter(lambda x: name in x, itr), set()) - set((name,))
set(['c', 'b'])
```

Comment: Note that this will mess up for `name`s that aren't a 1-character string.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is fine, but the solution is messy as you say:

```
def friends(itr, name):
    newset = [] # Your should probably make this a set
    for i in itr:
        if name in i:
            for j in i: # This loops is really not necessary 
                if j != name: 
                    newset.append(j)
    return set(newset)
```

Your code can be changed to something like this without any fancy tools:

```
def friends(itr, name):
    newset = set()
    for subset in itr:
        if name in subset:
            newset.update(subset)
    return newset.difference((name,))
```

Comment: I like naming the variables in a meaningful way

Answer (score 0):

1. First, filter out the sets which have the `name`, with a generator expression

   ```
   >>> filtered_sets = (item - {name} for item in itr if name in item)
   ```
2. Then, by iterating the generator, filter out the `name`

   ```
   >>> {item for items in filtered_sets for item in items if name != item}
   {'b', 'c'}
   ```